# postresql: How to input multiple ranges in a where statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select * 
from chartname
where itemvalue ~'^[A-Z]'
```

i also want to include [a-z], so I tried the following:

```
select * 
from chartname
where itemvalue ~'^[A-Z]' or ~'^[a-z]'
```

and

```
select * 
from chartname
where itemvalue ~'^[A-Z]' and ~'^[a-z]'
```

but this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

you first query could work if :

```
where itemvalue ~'^[A-Z]' or itemvalue ~'^[a-z]'
```

but here is a better way :

```
select * 
from chartname
where itemvalue ~'^[aA-zZ]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

where itemvalue ~ '^[a-zA-Z]'

This would be any value that starts with one of 52 Roman alphabet letters.